# How do I Detect Internet Explorer and Redirect on a Single Page Only

Tags: php, wordpress

I am experiencing a problem with an iframe on one of my WordPress pages - where Internet Explorer isn't displaying the correct source url within the iframe. I did some further investigation and found that this may be related to P3P Compliance on the source domain (which I don't have control over).

I'm still investigating a solution, however, in the mean time I'd like to be able to simply redirect just that page if IE (all versions) is detected. The URL for the page in question is http://test.centraltruckcenter.com/parts/iz_parts_online/

How can I do this please? I know that I could possibly insert an "if" statement into the header.php file, but that would apply it site-wide - which isn't what I'm looking for.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match `msie` on the user agent, but only on certain pages.

Place this at the very top (before any whitespace) of `header.php` of your theme.

```
<?php
$iepage = 9999999999;
if( is_page( $iepage ) ) {
    if( preg_match( '/(?:\b(MS)?IE\s+|\bTrident\/7\.0;.*\s+rv:)(\d+)/', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ) ) {
        header( "Location: http://yoursite.com/redirected.php" );
    }
}
?>
```

Of course you'll need to replace the page ID and location to redirect to.

Comment: Thanks. I did as you suggested, and it didn't work.  IE 8 & 9 simply return a 404 error and the redirect url is pre-pended to the URL as follows:  http://test.centraltruckcenter.com/parts/iz_parts_online/www.isuzutruckparts.net/?refid=61823.  Also, IE 11 simply ignores this code altogether.  I don't have a machine with IE 10 to test on.

Comment: Thanks, the update you provided worked.  Thank you very much.